# SQL Query not quite right with 3 joins

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get these three items out of my database however I don't think I'm using the correct `JOIN`.

**The 3 fields I need are:**

- `fldDate` - Which is held inside of `tblCompetition`
- `fldCatName` - Which is held inside of `tblCategory`
- `fldName` - Which is held inside of `tblImage`

**I have posted my Diagram of my tables with their field names to help explain:**

[image: Table Design]

My Query I have at present is:

```
$query ="SELECT `fldDate`, `fldCatName`, `fldName`
FROM `tblMembEntComp`
JOIN `tblImage` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID` = `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID`
JOIN `tblCompetition` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldCompID`= `tblCompetition`.`fldCompID`
WHERE `fldMemberID` = 1;"
```

The error appearing is: `Unknown column 'fldCatName' in 'field list'`, can someone explain where I'm going wrong.

Comment: `tblCategory` is not being joined so `fldCatName` doesn't exist.

Comment: So I need to 3 different JOINS ?

Comment: you need to join the `tblCategory` table to the `tblImage` table.

Comment: Hi @NigelRen I need to join on the competition table, as I need the CompDate that's held within that one

Comment: You're not selecting `fldCompDate`, why do you need to join with it?

Comment: @Barmar, yes, `fldDate` is on the `tblCompetition` table.

Comment: I would turn your Query around and start from the `tblCategory` but that is just me, I'm dyslexic so I do everything backwards.  Mainly because your not selecting any fields from the first table `tblMembEntComp`

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix So you're the one they created `RIGHT JOIN` for?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the table is the glue for all the other tables. Plus, if you read the whole question, the table is used in the `WHERE` clause so it is needed.

Comment: @Barmar - you should have seen me a few years ago trying to figure out the difference between `Right Join, Left Join, Inner Join, Join`  etc.  I sure now I know Join is Inner join, and that 80% you'll never need a Right Join, but...

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix, don't forget `FULL OUTER JOIN`, very handy. :-)

Comment: @WEI_DBA - I actually use a FULL OUTER JOIN to compare two databases and publish changes from one to the other.  We have a Live table our clients actively search on, then we have another table we make updates on.  It takes us some time to put a record together and we don't want clients searching on them tell its ready. We also allow a few clients to edit data in the same DB, so we allow them to edit the non live one and then review it before putting it live (there is also a versioning DB tied to this).

Comment: Your query would be easier to write/read/maintain and less error prone if you use aliases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not joining the `tblCategory` table with the `tblImage` table. That is why `MySQL` cannot find the field `fldCatName`
Your query should be

```
$query ="SELECT `fldDate`, `fldCatName`, `fldName`
FROM `tblMembEntComp`
JOIN `tblImage` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID` = `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID`
JOIN `tblCompetition` ON `tblMembEntComp`.`fldCompID`= `tblCompetition`.`fldCompID`
JOIN `tblCategory` ON `tblImage`.`fldCatID` = `tblCategory`.`fldCatID`
WHERE `tblMembEntComp`.`fldMemberID` = 1;"
```

You might want to use different kinds of joins depending on your use case. [This will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join/6188334#6188334)

Comment: Thank you @RisingSun so I tried this in phpMyAdmin and the error coming back was: `'fldMemberID' in where clause is ambiguous`. Is this because I have 3 joins which is perhaps too many?

Comment: it is because `fldMemberID` exists in multiple tables. You just need to specify which table to use. I will update the query above

Comment: YOU ROCK!!! P.S thank you guys or gals for all your comments etc, still a beginner here so I know the query I wrote is probably no where near the most efficient way.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again (hopefully you see this, say if I wanted this to change to `WHERE the  tblCategory . fldCatID  = 1` do you know why this brings back way too many results?

Comment: it is because you are using just `JOIN` statements. The link I provided in the answer gives good details on the different `JOIN` operations. Different combinations will give different results. I suggest you play around with those and start with just 2 tables so it is easier to understand.

Comment: Also, the number of results returned depends on the relationships of your tables: one to one, one to many, many to many.